# Multiply a column in every row

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains a column price with 3600 entries. I need to increase the price column by 9% or multiply the contents of the column price by 1.09 and place the updated price back in the price column. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should be pretty straightforward:

```
Update MyTable Set Price = Price*1.09
```